# "Stash pullrequest builder" plugin for Jenkins can't connect to Stash

Tags: ssl, jenkins, bitbucket-server

I try to integrate Stash and Jenkins together using "Stash pullrequest builder plugin". On their page it is said, that it should be available variable "${pullRequestId}". But I do not have it for my job. There is nothing in job logs for that error(build fails because variable ${pullRequestId} is not available), but I got the following exception in Jenkin's system logs:

stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.StashBuildTrigger.run() failed for hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@678cb9ff[JOB_NAME]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to process PR get request; https://STASH_URL/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT_NAME/repos/REPO_NAME/pull-requests?start=0
    at stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.stash.StashApiClient.getRequest(StashApiClient.java:180)
    at stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.stash.StashApiClient.getPullRequests(StashApiClient.java:68)
    at stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.StashRepository.getTargetPullRequests(StashRepository.java:69)
    at stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.StashPullRequestsBuilder.run(StashPullRequestsBuilder.java:30)
    at stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.StashBuildTrigger.run(StashBuildTrigger.java:218)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger.checkTriggers(Trigger.java:272)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger$Cron.doRun(Trigger.java:221)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1472)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:721)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.stash.StashApiClient.getRequest(StashApiClient.java:173)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1454)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 37 more

How to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Under "Advanced" Tab there is checkbox "Ignore ssl certificates". After checking that it was fine.